# Using Two GetDirectories and adding them together,

Tags: c#

How can I use two of the following Get Directories? I need to add them into one int, but when I use the following code I just get the same numbers.

```
var directoryInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test\");
int directoryCount = directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Length;

var directoryInfo2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test2\");
int directoryCount2 = directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Length;

int directoryCountMain = directoryCount + directoryCount2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `2` in `directoryCount2` initialization declaration.

You're using `directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Length` twice, instead of using `directoryInfo2` object when setting `directoryCount2`.

```
var directoryInfo2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test2\");
int directoryCount2 = directoryInfo2.GetDirectories().Length;
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the vague question I am new to c#.